# MySQL update timestamp on LOAD DATA INFILE IGNORE

Tags: mysql, linux, timestamp

I have written a couple of scripts which load data from switches into my MySQL database.

I have a table switch where I added a column "lastupdate".
The table switch looks like this:

```
create table switch (name varchar(15), swversion varchar(15), bootversion varchar(15), serialnumber varchar(30), rootbridge varchar(10), address varchar(20), switch_id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, lastupdate DATE , PRIMARY KEY(switch_id));
```

I have added a default timestamp for all the rows with the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE switch MODIFY lastupdate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
```

I am using `LOAD DATA INFILE IGNORE` to load my data in the dabatase with my "load data"-script.
Now I want to implement a MySQL command in my "load data"-script that automatically updates the timestamp for each row that got loaded (changed or not) in the table switch.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try use `LOAD DATA INFILE IGNORE ... SET lastupdate=NOW()`

Comment: Doesn't work, when rows are duplicate it skips the SET lastupdate=NOW()

Comment: If you are using `IGNORE` keywords input rows are skipped. Is not it? Or tell us about table metadata and how do you implement `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

Comment: Nvm, I solved it using a temporary table so I could get rid of the IGNORE and still be able to keep my id's from not auto-incrementing too much.
Thanks anyway!